# how do i increase the value of q by one without resetting each time opening the popup.js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
var i = 300;
chrome.storage.sync.set({q:i},()=>{console.log(i);});
chrome.storage.sync.get(['q'],(q)=>{document.querySelector("#here").innerHTML = q.q;});
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click",()=>{
  i++;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({q:i},()=>{var q = i;});
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['q'],(q)=>{document.querySelector("#here").innerHTML = q.q;})
},false);
```

q always updates to 300 each time extension is opened how do i update it and not reset,
is there a way to do it without background page and just use popup.js?

Comment: Your question could be easier to answer if you clarified it a bit. Try to add some more details and context.

Comment: initially i is supposed to be 300 and after opening the popup and clicking the number goes up by one and after closing the popup and opening it again it should be what was the last number it is

Comment: Welcome to SO, What you are doing is declaring the var i =300, that is resetting the value each time. One workaround is to use some global variable or local storage. Then you can call and update it each time rather than creating 'i' each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the second line `chrome.storage.sync.set({q:i},()=>{console.log(i);});`
   it always overwrites the storage with `i` which is `300`.
2. Read the storage on start and put the result in `i`
3. Listen to changes in the storage and update `i` and DOM automatically - this will handle both your own changes and remote changes due to browser sync or changes in popups open in other browser windows.

```js
let i;

chrome.storage.sync.get({q: 300}, res => {
  useValue(res.q);
});

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(changes => {
  if (changes.q) {
    useValue(changes.q.newValue);
  }
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({q: i + 1});
});

function useValue(val) {
  i = val;
  document.querySelector('#here').textContent = val;
}
```

Comment: what if i want to type it like instead of q:300 q:i and i = 300;

Comment: See tutorials for DOM - you can use an `input` element and listen to `input` event on that element.

Comment: i saw an extension doing it through input but i was wondering if i could just type the value within the js file as a variable and not the value 300

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. Yes, you can do that. The potential advantage of doing it my way is that the variable won't have the wrong value until the storage is accessed.

Comment: okay your answer actually helped what i'm trying to do so thanks :D